# XMLHttpRequest Object with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, xmlhttprequest

The full jQuery $.ajax syntax allows me to do this

```
var obj = {'a':1,'b':2};
$.ajax({url:url,dataType:'json',type:'POST',
data:{zip:'602'},beforeSend:function(xhr){$(xhr).data('obj',obj)}}).
done(function(data,state,xhr){console.log(data);console.log($(xhr).data('obj'))})
```

In Google Chrome on Windows this works perfectly - when AJAX returns I can access the stored object However, I do not know if this would work equally well across a whole range of browsers.  The ones I am principally concerned with are Android native, Chrome for Android, iOS Safari, Firefox, Safari and IE9+ on Windows, Safari on Mac OSs.

I realize that I can probably establish at least a part of the answer to this question by running a few tests but getting setup to do them all would consume that all too precious resource - time.  So I am hoping that someone here has the answer.

I guess it all boils down to this - is the XMLHTTPRequest always, within reason, guaranteed to be a first class citizen of the DOM.

Comment: You asked 2 questions: 1) if jQuery's ajax is cross browser, then 2) if XMLHTTPRequest is a first-class citizen cross browser. The answers are yes and no respectively.

Comment: Are you suggesting that relying on tagging object data to $(xhr) before the call and then testing for that object data after the call is not safe to do with all recent browsers? p.s. - I didn't realize that my question somehow asked if jQuery ajax is cross browser.  That was not the intention.

Comment: jQuery uses a fake xhr, so when you attach to `xhr` on beforeSend it may not *actually* be a real `XMLHttpRequest` under the hood. But the fake xhr is constant through out, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks.  I cannot vote up your comment or else I would have done so.